# iText: password trouble implementing digital signature for PDF file on server

Tags: java, pdf, itext, keystore, pkcs#12

New user for iText trying to get example code adapted from sample 3.1 and code sample 3.2 in https://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures

I've included code snippets below FYI.

I had the hosting provider create a `.pfx` file from a GlobalSign certificate (they don't provide `.p12` file). They issued the following linux command:

```
# openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey www.mydomain.com.key 
  -in ../certs/www.mydomain.com.crt -certfile ../certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

where `ca-bundle.crt` comes from GlobalSign. To get a `.p12`, I just copied the `.pfx` file into a new file with a `.p12` extension. From what I can see online, people have done this before (not related to iText) and succeeded, as the `.pfx` file and `.p12` files are binary equivalents.

To verify, one can type at the linux prompt:

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in /path/to/file/cert.pfx
```

and it then asks for an import password, and there is none, so just hit enter, and then it asks for the private pass phrase, which I enter (e.g. `myPrivateCertPassword`), and then it displays my private cert, GlobalSign's public cert, and my private key.

Now's where I get confused. There is no import password, so I've tried the following attempts in iText (as shown in the snippets below):

```
  ks.load(new FileInputStream(CONSTANTS.CERTIFICATE_PATH), null);
  ks.load(new FileInputStream(CONSTANTS.CERTIFICATE_PATH), "".toCharArray());
```

neither one works. The first gives a runtime error:

```
java.io.IOException: PKCS12 key store mac invalid - wrong password or corrupted file.
```

and the second one gives run time error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : org/bouncycastle/cert/X509CertificateHolder
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Where, exactly, does the password used in the `ks.load()` line of code come from (GlobalSign? the server hosting company? me?). Is this called the `export key` when I issue the above export command?

Thanks in advance for any comments.

-------- code snippets follow ---------

```
public static final char[] PASS = "myPrivateCertPassword".toCharArray();   
public static final String CERTIFICATE_PATH = "/path/to/file/cert.p12";
```

In main():

```
BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
Security.addProvider(provider);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", provider.getName()); 
ks.load(new FileInputStream(CONSTANTS.CERTIFICATE_PATH), null);
// ks.load(new FileInputStream(CONSTANTS.CERTIFICATE_PATH), "".toCharArray()); // this also fails
String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, CONSTANTS.PASS);
Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
sign(userFile, userFile_signed, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, 
   provider.getName(),CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test", "Ghent", null, null, null, 0);
```

Outside main():

```
public void sign(
String src,
String dest,
Certificate[] chain,
PrivateKey pk,
String digestAlgorithm,
String provider,
CryptoStandard subfilter,
String reason,
String location,
Collection<CrlClient> crlList,
OcspClient ocspClient, TSAClient tsaClient,
int estimatedSize)
throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
  // Creating the reader and the stamper
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
  FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
  PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
  // Creating the appearance
  PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
  appearance.setReason(reason);
  appearance.setLocation(location);
  appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
  // Creating the signature
  ExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
  ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
  MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain,
  crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize, subfilter);
 }
```

UPDATE 1:

I created a new cert.pfx file by exporting as above, but this time I entered an "export password", as `exportPassword`, which I inserted as:

```
  ks.load(new FileInputStream(CONSTANTS.CERTIFICATE_PATH), "exportPassword".toCharArray());
```

but this gives a new runtime error:

```
 java.io.IOException: exception decrypting data - java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
```

Am i getting closer?

UPDATE 2:

I installed JCE per Bruno's comment, and now I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : org/bouncycastle/tsp/TimeStampTokenInfo
```

UPDATE 3:

I was able to clear the above error by also adding bcpkix-jdk15on-149.jar from www.bouncycastle.org to the /lib directory, and adding the following to the java program:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider; // this was already there
import org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampTokenInfo; // this is new and fixed the above error
```

Now I can see the digital signature!

UPDATE 4:

For those interested, see my follow-up post here:
[iText: what type of certificates do people use to automate PDF signing on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437354/itext-what-type-of-certificates-do-people-use-to-automate-pdf-signing-on-linux)

Comment: Regarding the BouncyCastle error: which version of BC are you using? Regarding the *Illegal key size*: what is the key size and does the key usage allow digital signing? (Not all of them do.) Finally, did you install the extra JCE (the standard SDK doesn't allow you to use long key sizes).

Comment: Thaks Bruno, I'm using BouncyCastle bcprov-jdk15on-149.jar (the latest). I'll have to check what the key size is, and if it allows digital signing. And, I haven't installed any extra JCE -- are you referring to `Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7`? (if so, I haven't installed, do I need to?)

Comment: The JCE was basically the culprit. See Updates 2 and 3 above. Bruno, thanks so much. Excellent documentation by the way in http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures . It really helped a LOT. If you submit your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm writing a new (free e)book. As a result, I'm not as active on SO as I used to be. Thanks for updating the question and thanks for the offer to accept the answer should I write one, but more important: I'm happy you were able to solve the problem.